# Merge two datasets based on specific column data

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas datasets

old:

```
|   alpha |       beta          | zeta        | id       | rand | numb|
| ------  | ------------------  | ------------| ------   | --- -| ----|
|   1     |        LA           |   bev       |  A100    | D    | 100 |
|   1     |        LA           |   malib     |  C150    | Z    | 150 |
|   2     |        NY           |   queens    |  B200    | N    | 200 |
|   2     |        NY           |   queens    |  B200    | N    | 200 |
|   3     |        Chic         |   lincpark  |  E300    | T    | 300 |
|   3     |        NY           |   Bronx     |  F300    | M    | 300 |
```

new:

```
|   alpha |       beta          |    zeta        |  id   | numb |
| ------  | ------------------  | ---------------| ------| -----|
|   1     |        LA           |   Hwood        |  Q    | Q400 |
|   2     |        NY           |   queens       |  B    | B200 |
|   3     |        Chic         |   lincpark     |  D    | D300 |
```

(Columns and data don't mean anything in particular, just an example).

I want to merge datasets in a way such that

1. IF old.alpha, old.beta, and old.zeta = their corresponding new columns and If old.id = new.numb, you only keep the entry from the old table. (in this case the row 2 on the old with queens would be kept as opposed to row 2 on new with queens)

Note that rows 3 and 4 on old are the same, but we still keep both. If there were 2 duplicates of these rows in new we consider them as 1-1 corresponding. If maybe there were 3 duplicates on new of rows 3 and 4 on old, then 2 are considered copies (and we don't add them, but we would add the third when we merge them)

2. IF old.alpha, old.beta, and old.zeta = their corresponding new columns and If old.numb is contained inside new.numb, you only keep the entry from the old table. (in this case the row 5 on the old with lincpark would be kept as opposed to row 3 on new with lincpark, because 300 is contained in new.numb)
3. Otherwise add the new data as new data, keeping the new table's id and numb, and having null for any extra columns that the old table has (new's row 1 with hollywood)

I have tried various merging methods along with the drop_duplicates method. The problem with the the latter is that I attempted to drop duplicates having the same alpha beta and zeta, but often they were deleted from the same datasource, because the rows were exactly the same.

This is what ultimately needs to be shown when merging. 2 of the rows in new were duplicates, one was something to be added.

```
|   alpha |       beta          | zeta        | id       | rand | numb|
| ------  | ------------------  | ------------| ------   | --- -| ----|
|   1     |        LA           |   bev       |  A100    | D    | 100 |
|   1     |        LA           |   malib     |  C150    | Z    | 150 |
|   2     |        NY           |   queens    |  B200    | N    | 200 |
|   2     |        NY           |   queens    |  B200    | N    | 200 |
|   3     |        Chic         |   lincpark  |  E300    | T    | 300 |
|   3     |        NY           |   Bronx     |  F300    | M    | 300 |
|   1     |        LA           |   Hwood     |  Q       |      | Q400|
```

Answer (score 0):

We can merge two Data frames in several ways. Most common way in python is using merge operation in Pandas.
Assuming df1 is your new and df2 is the old

Follow merge by IF conditions.

`import pandas
dfinal = df1.merge(df2, on="alpha", how = 'inner')`

For merging based on columns of different dataframe, you may specify left and right common column names specially in case of ambiguity of two different names of same column, lets say - 'idold' as 'idnew'.

```
dfinal = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on='alpha', right_on='id')
```

If you want to be even more specific, you may read the documentation of pandas merge operation.

Also specify If conditions and perform merge operations by rows, and then drop the remaining columns in a temporary dataframe. And add values to that dataframe according to conditions.
I understand the answer is a little bit complex, but so is your question. Cheers :)